# Проблема с выводом данных из JSON в ListView

Tags: android

Почему-то список оказывается пустой. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема

Класс GetJSON

```
class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private ListView listView;
    private Context context;
    private String jsonURL;
    private ArrayList<String> itemsList;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String resultJson = "";

    public GetJSON(ListView listView, Context context, String jsonURL, ArrayList<String> itemsList, ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter) {
        this.listView = listView;
        this.context = context;
        this.jsonURL = jsonURL;
        this.itemsList = itemsList;
        this.arrayAdapter = arrayAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // получаем данные с внешнего ресурса
        try {
            URL url = new URL(jsonURL);

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            resultJson = buffer.toString();

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultJson;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
        super.onPostExecute(strJson);

        JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;

        try {
            dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
            JSONArray itemsArray = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("items");

            //Перебираем все элементв
            for (int i = 0; i < itemsArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject itemsObject = itemsArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String title = itemsObject.optString("title");

                itemsList.add(title);

                Log.d("RTRT", title);
            }

            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Класс MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<String> strs = new ArrayList<>();
    final String urlWebService = "https://site.ru/test/famous_laks.php";
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        new GetJSON(listView, MainActivity.this, urlWebService, strs, arrayAdapter).execute();

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent nIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ItemActivity.class);
                TextView textView = (TextView) view;
                String strText = textView.getText().toString(); // получаем текст нажатого элемента
                nIntent.putExtra("title", strText);
                nIntent.putExtra("introtext", 1);
                startActivity(nIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

При выполнении этой строки `Log.d("RTRT", title);` заголовки выводятся в лог. Не могу понять почему список оказывается пустой

Comment: попробуй arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); в onPostExecute

Comment: добавил. Ошибку выдало java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference и строке arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: а, ну правильно - у тебя адаптер создается после new GetJSON(listView,... adapter :) создание адаптера и GetJSON поменяй местами...

Comment: Да, точно. Заработало. Спасибо большое.

Comment: на здоровье :) может и notifyDataSetChanged не нужен - можно попробовать без него, проблема получается была в setAdapter(null)...

Comment: Да, я убрал notifyDataSetChanged без него тоже работает.